# AWS Amplify - request signature, key, signing method

Tags: aws-amplify

I have been working with my React app with Amplify for a while now. When doing amplify push today, I got the following error:

```
An error occurred during the push operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

What is this and how do I fix it? I had to uninstall and then reinstall some AWS amplify things because amplify is a dumpster fire. Did something go wrong there? Do I need to reconfigure?

Comment: Why would anyone want to close this question? If there's a simple answer, post a link.